# XSL child element to parent attribute, part deux: order of elements matters?

Tags: xml, xslt

So, based on my previous question ([XSLT transform child element to attribute in the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32704959/xslt-transform-child-element-to-attribute-in-the-parent)) I want to use data in a child as an attribute in the parent element. The problem is that when I convert an element that has another child before "poolColor", the poolColor somehow is not added as an attribute.

Working:

```
<Exchange xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <parent xsi:type="SinglePool">
        <poolColor colorType="Basecolor" colorKey="GN"/>
        <poolLength type="full_length" length="2"/>
    </parent>
</Exchange>
```

Results in:

```
<Exchange xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <parent xsi:type="SinglePool" basecolor="GN">
        <poolLength type="full_length" length="2" />
    </parent>
</Exchange>
```

Not working:

```
<Exchange xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <parent xsi:type="SinglePool">
        <poolLength type="full_length" length="2" id="N7" />
        <poolColor colorType="Basecolor" colorKey="GN" id="N3" />
    </parent>
</Exchange>
```

Results in:

```
<Exchange xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <parent xsi:type="SinglePool">
        <poolLength type="full_length" length="2" id="N7" />
    </parent>
</Exchange>
```

The XSL code that I am using is the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="poolColor">
        <xsl:attribute name='{translate(@colorType,"BC","bc")}'>
        <xsl:value-of select="@colorKey" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would be glad if someone could shed some light into why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xsl:attribute` in the second example does not work since `<poolength>`has been added to `<parent>`. This is an error according to the XSLT rec:

> The following are all errors:
>   Adding an attribute to an element after children have been added to
>   it; implementations may either signal the error or ignore the
>   attribute.
>   
> ...

The following would work since any `poolColor` child is handled before the other content:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|poolColor" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[name()!='poolColor']" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Oh. So then what would be a possible way around this? Adding this attribute first and then copying the rest of the children?